# Separating the parameter passed in the Header in the Get Request from Angular at the Spring backend

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, http

I am very new to Rest services in Spring. I followed a tutorial and found that It is secure to send a parameter to the backend in the following way.

```
getCompanyDetails(username:string): Observable<CompanyObject>{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic '+btoa(username)})
    return this.http.get<CompanyObject>("http://localhost:8080/company/getCompany",{headers:headers});
}
```

Can someone please show me the way to read the username at the backend? The code I wrote can read the "authorization" part, but still the username is encoded. Is there a way to directly read this username? My backend code is as follows. Thank you.

```
@GetMapping("company/getCompany")
    private void getCompany(@RequestHeader("authorization") HttpHeaders header){
    System.out.println(header);
}
```

Comment: Just decode from base 64 in Java

Answer (score 2):

In your Angular code , before you are adding the username to the header, you are passing it to a function btoa(), which I presume is encoding the username according to a particular algorithm. The springboot backend response handlers will not decode anything that is manually added by a developer. It will handle gettig the headers from the request and it will decode the request to get the request header values in case of any standard encryptions like when we use https. But in your case you have the `Authorization` value like `'Basic'+some encoded value`. So in this case, you will have to manually decode it once you get the value from header at the controller.

Comment: Thank you so much! It sounds silly now for asking that question, but I was confused! Thank you for being generous and helping me out.

Comment: @OshanaDissanayake No issues. Happy to be of help